# Where can I download the ISO torrents for Ubuntu?

Tags: release-management, bittorrent

Where can I download the latest Ubuntu 12.04.1 (Precise Pangolin) ISO torrent files?

I use uTorrent for downloading torrents.

> 1. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/148815/58612) has the [index page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)
> 2. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/148816/58612) direct links to the `.torrent` files.

Comment: Why do you need torrent files? Wouldn't a magnet link be enough?

Comment: :) actually Manet link not work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can download the `.torrent` files for all versions from the [alternative downloads page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads). Use any torrent client (including *uTorrent*) to then get the CD image (`.iso`) file with it.

Answer (score 15):

### Direct links to all Ubuntu 12.04.1 Precise ISO torrents:

#### These will open directly in your torrent client *(uTorrent, Transmission, etc.)!*

1. [**Desktop**
   32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)

   - [Desktop
     64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)
2. [**Alternate** (text-based installer)
   32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso.torrent)

   - [Alternate (text-based installer)
     64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)
3. [**Server**
   64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso.torrent)

   - [Server
     32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-server-i386.iso.torrent)

Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can find a few torrent trackers specializing in linux-related torrents, so for example you can find a lot of Ubuntu torrents here:
http://linuxtracker.org/index.php?page=torrents&category=563